# Prove or disprove that the subspace topology on $A′=A∪\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

I asked a question earlier where I was trying to figure out if the subspace topology on $A$ that is inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is the discrete topology.

$A=\{\frac{1}{n}|n∈\mathbb{N}_+\}⊂\mathbb{R}$

The answer reached was that the subspace was indeed the discrete topology using the distances between adjacent points in $A$ and neighborhoods around them. In other words, a given point $x∈A$ has an open neighborhood $U_x⊆\mathbb{R}$ around it such that no other point $y∈A$ lies inside $U_x$. We know $\{x\}$ is open in the subspace topology and - since $x$ was arbitrary - $A$ has to be discrete.

@WiktorVacca suggested I consider $A′=A∪\{0\}$ and see if the subspace topology on $A'$ under similar conditions is also the discrete topology.

Obviously, if $\{0\}$ is added to $A$ via a union, we get a situation where the distance between points in $A'$ decreases to some infinitesimally small distance as they approach $0$. (i.e. distance is smaller as $n \rightarrow \infty$) **and** where $0$ is a point in $A'$.

I would assume that the idea of this problem is that we will eventually reach a situation where the neighborhood around a point in $A'$ will be such that
$\{\frac{1}{n}\}=A'∩(\frac{1}{n}−δ,\frac{1}{n}+δ)$ has $0$ in it, no matter how we choose $δ$.

But if you consider the nature of the natural numbers, it doesn't seem like there is any particular number where this can happen. There will always be a slightly smaller next point to choose from in the form $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Just use some fraction of the distance between these two points as your neighborhood.

Am I looking at this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Firm it up by appealing to the definitions.  If $A'$ is to be discrete, then $\{0\}$ should be an open set in the subspace topology on $A'$.  Then
$$
\{0\} = A' \cap \mathcal{O}
$$
for some set $\mathcal{O}$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, $0 \in \mathcal{O}$ and so there must be a $\delta >0$ with $0 \in (-\delta, \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.  But this can't work for reasons you've pointed out:  choose $N$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{N} \in (-\delta, \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.  Then $A' \cap \mathcal{O}$ contains $0$ as well as $\frac{1}{N}$, a contradiction.  Hence $A'$ is not discrete.